# Where to put custom type definitions that can be import via '$lib/types'?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I created a SvelteKit skeleton project with TypeScript syntax. Under `src/lib/` I created a component `Example.svelte` with the following content:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type {ExampleType} from '$lib/types'

    const example: ExampleType = { /* ... */}
</script>
```

VSCode tells me: `Cannot find module '$lib/types' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I tried putting the definition in `app.d.ts`, both, under the global declaration and within the `App` namespace. (see [SvelteKit docs about types](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#app)). I also restarted the dev server in between the edits.

Where do I have to put the definition of `ExampleType` such that I can import it via `$lib/types`? Is there perhaps a better way to define and import custom type definitions?

Comment: Where do you store the type in? It should be put inside `src/lib/types.ts` and need to be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lib` is an alias for the directory `src/lib`, so `$lib/types` would reference either of:

- `src/lib/types.ts`
- `src/lib/types/index.ts`